# How to redirect request from nginx reverse proxy back to localhost

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm new to nginx and docker-compose. 
I have a docker-compose which contains a nginx-reverse-proxy and many web APIs called webapi01, webapi02 ...

In nginx-reverse-proxy,  I have

```
  location /app1/{
        proxy_pass http://webapi01:5000/;
    }
    location /app2/{
        proxy_pass http://webapi02:5000/;
    }
```

and they are working fine.

Now after startup my docker-compose, I want to debug my webapi01 by modifying the location that points to my webApi01 and expecting the request will hit the debug instance webapi01 which is listing at http://localhost:5000

```
 location /app1/{
     #proxy_pass http://webapi01:5000/;
     # what should be here so the request will be forward to the localhost(the machine, not the docker-compose ) so I can debug my webapi01
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
 }
```

However, I could not make it work. The log shows the error: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream .......

So the question is how to redirect the request from nginx-reverse-proxy back to the host machine (localhost)?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

thanks,

Austin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. https://medium.com/@bsamartins/reverse-proxy-nginx-docker-container-to-localhost-7ebc53577192

```
location /app1/{
     # this line will connect to your running instance in docker-compose
     #proxy_pass http://webapi01:5000/;
     # this line will forward to the localhost(the machine, not the docker-compose ) so I can debug my webapi01
     proxy_pass http://docker.for.win.localhost:5000/;
 }
```